# Does anyone know how to drop a pin on AppleMaps via URL schema

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, apple-maps

Does anyone know how to open up Apple Maps from inside the app and drop a pin on a geolocation using URL scheme? It looks like I can only drop the pin at the address but not the geo location.

[This is the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/MapLinks.html) I'm using and it's a little brief.

Answer (score 6):

Use http://maps.apple.com/?q=lat,lng.

This will work. It is working for me.

Comment: This is only opening the map with that location centered and not dropping the pin as required by @sonoluminescence

Answer (score 4):

If you're using iOS 6, then it's better to use [`MKMapItem`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapItem_class/Reference/Reference.html).

For example:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D myCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(123, 456);

MKPlacemark *myPlacemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:myCoordinate addressDictionary:nil];

MKMapItem *mapItem = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:myPlacemark];
mapItem.name = @"A Cool Place";
[mapItem openInMapsWithLaunchOptions:nil];
```

Comment: Is there a way to set the zoom without using an `MKCoordinateSpan`?

Comment: @fumoboy007: This one does not use the URL scheme as asked in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following format to drop a pin at the location:

http://maps.apple.com/?ll=34.2390,108.8887&q=Address%20Name

OR

maps:ll=34.2390,108.8887&q=Address%20Name

Parameters:

*q* => Name of the location

*ll* => Coordinates of the location

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html