# Show a pin in the Apple Map Location

Tags: objective-c

i need help for open location in apple maps

Example:

```
http://maps.apple.com/?ll=28.387030,36.593558
```

I want to show the pin

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does anyone know how to drop a pin on AppleMaps via URL schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13664652/does-anyone-know-how-to-drop-a-pin-on-applemaps-via-url-schema)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That can be achieved by adding the **q**-parameter to your URL

```
https://maps.apple.com/?&ll=28.388281,36.589572&q=My%20Location
```

Comment: Thanks Frank 

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept my answer if it solved your problem.